# Direct product of simple groups

Tags: group-theory, simple-groups

Let $G=H_1\times H_2$, $H_1,H_2$ are simple groups. Let $L\vartriangleleft G$ ($L$ isn't trivial). Show that $L$ isomorphic to $H_1$ or $H_2$.

I tried to construct "projections" of $L$ on $H_1,H_2$, I only showed that their images must be trivial, but I'm not sure if it's the right direction.

Comment: Hint: What is $L\cap (H_1\times 1)$?

Comment: $H_1\times 1$ or $1\times 1$.. Tried this direction too

Comment: Ok and what is $L\cap (1\times H_2)$?

Comment: If $N_1,N_2$ are normal subgroups of $G$ then $N_1\cap N_2$ is also normal.

Comment: My problem was how to get a contradiction if both intersections are $1\times 1$.. I guess I'm missing something

Comment: if $L\cap H_1=1$ and $L\cap H_2=1$ then $L=1\times 1$.

Comment: can't see why.. what is the problem with $(a,b)\in L$, $a,b\neq 1$ ?

Comment: @DerekHolt: He just tries to prove that $L$ is isomorphic to $H_1$ or $H_2$, **not** that it is $H_1$ or $H_2$, so the statement is OK.

Comment: As the projection is onto, the image of a normal subgroup is normal.

Comment: @j.p. Good point! I've deleted my comment. But I think the proof will need to treat the abelian and mnonabelian cases seperately.

Comment: @daPollak: I forgot to mention that you might need to prove that the image is normal in the first line of my answer (in case your lecture didn't cover it) and the "it is easy to show" might need a very short proof, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the projection $p_1 : G \to H_1$ is onto, the image of a normal subgroup of $G$ is normal in $H_1$. As $H_1$ is simple we get that either $p_1(L) = 1$ or $p_1(L) = H_1$.

If $p_1(L) = 1$ then $L$ is a subgroup of $H_2$. As it is a non-trivial normal subgroup of the simple group $H_2$, we get $L=H_2$. (I do not distinguish between inner and outer direct products.)

If $p_1(L) = H_1$ look at the kernel $K = H_2\cap L$ of $p_1$ restricted to $L$. As $K$ is normal in the simple group $H_2$ we know that either $K=1$ or $K=H_2$ holds. In case of $K=1$ we have that $L$ is isomorphic to $H_1$. If $K=H_2$ then it is easy to show that $L=H_1\times H_2 = G$ contradicting that $L$ is a proper subgroup of $G$.

(Also to my surprise no need for extra treatment of the case $H_1 = H_2$ abelian.)

Comment: Exchanging $H_1$ and $H_2$ one sees that the case $H_1 \cap L = 1 = H_2 \cap L$ can only occur when $H_1$ and $H_2$ are isomorphic. Myself's answer shows that both have to be additionally abelian.

Answer (score 3):

Let me focus on the case where $L\cap (1\times H_1) = L\cap (H_2\times 1) =1$ since from the comments it seems that's where your main difficulty lies. As Derek Holt notices, this case requires some special attention because $C_p\times C_p$ has 'unexpected' normal subgroups.

Assume that $L>1$ and consider any $(a,b)\in L$, $(a,b)\neq 1$ Consider any $x\in H_2$. Then $(a,b)^{(1,x)} = (a,b^x)\in L$ because $L$ is normal. Therefore also $(a^{-1},b^{-1})(a,b^x) = (1,b^{-1}b^x)\in L$. But this implies that $b=b^x$.

And this for all $x\in H_2$, so $b$ would be central in $H_2$. This implies $H_2$ must be abelian, i.e. cyclic of prime order. Similarly $H_1$ is cyclic of prime order and then it's easy to finish with what you know about subgroups of $C_p\times C_p$ and $C_p\times C_q$.