# If a group $ G$ is not simple does it follow that it is isomorphic to the direct product of two nontrivial groups?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be not simple does it follow that $G=G_1\times G_2$, where $G_1$ and $G_2$ are nontrivial groups?

Edit: Wait is the answer $G_1=N\lhd G$ and $G_2=G/N$?

Comment: That is not the answer: consider $C_4$ and $C_2 \times C_2$, which are not isomorphic, not simple, but would have the same $G_1, G_2$ in your representation.

Comment: Your question is a very natural one, but simplicity for groups is related to composition series, not to direct  product decomposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the group $Q_8 = \{1,-1,i,-i,j,-j,k,-k\}$ where $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = -1$, and $ij = -ji = k, jk = -kj = i, ki = -ik = j$. This group is not simple, as *every* subgroup is normal.

Can this group be written as a direct product of $2$ (proper, nontrivial) subgroups? (Hint: one of the subgroups would have to have order $2$).

Answer (score 1):

another example: 
Consider the non-commutative group $S_3$, which has a normal subgroup $A_3=C_3$ and $S_3 / C_3 = C_2$ , but $C_3 \times C_2 = C_6$ is commutative.

Answer (score 1):

Note: conversely, if $G = G_1 \times G_2$, where $G_1$ and $G_2$ are simple, and $N$ is a non-trivial proper normal subgroup of $G$, then $N \cong G_1$ or $N \cong G_2$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1112010/direct-product-of-simple-groups).